# Open python file on computer login

Tags: windows, python-3.x, startup, autostart

Is there a way to run a python file when the computer wakes up, as in once you are logged in? I have not tried anything yet.

Comment: Well, that's too bad, because a 5sec Google search would have pointed you [here](http://superuser.com/questions/15596/automatically-run-a-script-when-i-log-on-to-windows)...

Comment: @xbug but I don't see how that is for a python file, that seems to be just writing into a txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7 for how to make the program you have created run on start-up. I would suggest renaming the python file from .py to .pyw as well though.